# how to underline/change color menu item?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am using this code to create menu and menu items .What i want to do is when i click anymenu item it should be underlined showing that my current selection is this or is changes color ...

My code..

```
CCMenuItem *AutoFire1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Auto" target:self selector:@selector(AutoFire:)];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:AutoFire1, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(170, 100);

//  [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];

    [self addChild:menu];


    CCMenuItem *MaunualFire1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Maunal" target:self selector:@selector(MaunalFire:)];

    CCMenu *menu2 = [CCMenu menuWithItems:MaunualFire1, nil];
    menu2.position = ccp(300, 100);

    //  [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];

    [self addChild:menu2];
```

and the function that runs on touch here are...

```
  -(void) AutoFire: (id) sender 
    {
AutoFire=1; //Underline menuitem or change color to show current selection...
     }
     -(void) MaunalFire: (id) sender
    {
AutoFire=0;
}
```

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `CCMenuItem *AutoFire1` and `CCMenuItem *MaunualFire1` instance variables of your layer.

In your method for when they are pressed, alter them accordingly to do what you want them to do.

I can't remember of the top of my head what the code is to change the colour of a CCMenuItemFont but you'd do something along the lines of

```
   -(void) AutoFire: (id) sender 
    {
    AutoFire=1;
    AutoFire1.color = ccc3(r,g,b);
    }
```

Comment: this worked :)...
[(CCMenuItemFont *)MaunualFire1 setColor:ccc3(255,255,255)];